# Generate unique random number perform insert,update,delete show into textbox?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I need to generate unique random number to show into the textbox value and also perform insert,delete,update operation using java script. I need your solution which is better way using mysql or java script.? I'm trying java script and facing problem i could not show unique id.?

My java script code:

```
document.getElementbyId("random").value=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
```

Comment: why do you need random number, is it gonna be stored in database? are you gonna use it with some other param so that it is unique, may timestamp or userid?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want help with?  Your line of code for filling a field with a random number looks fine if your HTML matches the code.  As for operating on a mysql database, you will want to do some internet research on doing an Ajax call from your javascript to a server that has access to the mysql database.

Comment: Yes I need to stored in databse.This is little bit about my question, In my html having one of the field scanId, which are the requirement having system generates a random number for every user. Really I don't have idea about this how do i do it? also I have 4buttons add,update,delete,cancel.

Comment: In my attached java script code works fine.. but the problem is which is didn't create unique number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of code you're showing I can't give a specific answer, but I think the general idea is that you want a unique but random number assign into your text box?

unique number is easy, use things like timestamp. But if you need unique and random at the same time, the only "easy" method is generate a random number and check it against your database for duplicates.

just a heads up, if your random range is only from 0 to 10 it'll get fill up very quickly and duplicates will happens a lot, which slow down your program. I'd suggest at least a 10 times or more difference in the range of the random number and the expected total count of usage, like if you expect this program to run less than 10 times, use a range at least 100+

edit:

it is almost impossible to be sure a random number is unique unless you have all your previous generated number to check against. THAT SAID, there is a chessy way I can think of to kinda make a unique-random number, but it scales REALLY BAD the more you generates. The core idea is to change the FORMAT of the number everytime.

for example

1) generate a 2 digit number the first time, a 3 digit number the second time, a 4 digit number......

2) change the range of number, 0-10 for the first number, 11-20 the second number, 21-30 .......

Comment: Thanks Jacky Cheng...In my attached java script code works fine.. but the problem is which is didn't create unique number.Is there anything way to set unique random number in java script.?

Comment: Thanks Jacky Cheng.I'll try to implement it. Is there anything way to create auto generated random number in mysql?I'll try for both side... Once againg thanks...

Comment: try     FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min>   for SQL side, good luck. <min> & <max> is the minimum and maximum value of your range by the way.